# Python on Apache: Internal Server Error

Tags: python, apache

I'm getting `Internal Server Error` from my Python script on Apache.

The script has `chmod 755` and is in a directory different from `cgi-bin`.

Its content is

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
print "test"
```

I'm on shared hosting with limited options. In particular I cannot view the Apache logfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache tries to execute the script, but fails to do so because it is missing `Options +ExecCGI` in the `.htaccess` located in the script's directory.

It is important to begin the script with the two lines

```
#!/usr/bin/python
print "Content-Type: text/html\n"
```

Without those, or without a trailing `\n`, Apache would throw an `Internal Server Error`, too.